# What should I do to make PyAudio work in M1 Macbook Pro?

Tags: python, apple-m1, pyaudio

I am facing some problem with PyAudio in M1 Macbook Pro. First I installed portaudio with this command

```
brew install portaudio --HEAD
```

Then I installed PyAudio

```
python3 -m pip install pyaudio --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="-I/opt/homebrew/include" --global-option="-L/opt/homebrew/lib"
```

But when I test it by importing pyaudio, it gives me this error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'
```

Help me please!